# How to get the first date of ISO year for the current date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`GETDATE()` returns the current date.

`YEAR(GETDATE())` returns the current year given the current date. Appending `01-01` results in `01-01-2021`.

How can I derive the start of ISO year? Expected output: 04-01-2021

Comment: Maybe clarify, for those of us who don't know, what a ISO year is?

Answer (score 0):

An article on calculating the start of iso year in Excel can be found here:- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/09/17/calculate-the-iso-start-of-year-date/

I converted that into the SQL below. I've included the interim calculations I made as I was working through the conversion but the last column has the requested calculation.

```
SELECT
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1 ,4) AS 'FOURTHJAN',
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1 ,2) AS 'SECONDJAN',
    DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1 ,2)) AS "SECONDJANDAYOFWEEK",
    DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1 ,2)) % 7 AS "ADJUSTMENT",
    DATEADD(day, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1 ,2)) % 7), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1 ,4)) AS "STARTOFISOYEAR"
```

EDIT:-

Here's the code for a function that uses the above calculation

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StartISOYear (@DATE datetime)
RETURNS Date
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(DATEADD(day, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@DATE), 1 ,2)) % 7), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@DATE), 1 ,4)));
END;
GO
```

Which can be run using :-

```
SELECT dbo.StartISOYear(GETDATE())
```